# After updating Laravel from 5.8 to 7 - changes?

Tags: php, laravel

i've updated my Laravel app from v5.8 to v7. It's working pretty well but I'm struggeling with one thing.
I have a function called cityList() that gives me all cities from the DB. But there seems to be a change in the syntax from version 5 to 7 according to the output array.

Here is my function:

```
public function cityList() {
        $cities = [];
        foreach($this->messages()->with('city')->select('messages.*', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as counter'))
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(24)->toDateTimeString())
                    ->groupBy('city_id')
                    ->get() as $_message) {
            $city = $_message->city;
            if($city) {
                if($_message->counter >= config('options.city_list_count')) {
                    $url = null;
                    if(Route::has('provider.city')) {
                        $url = route('provider.city', [
                            $this->name_slug,
                            $city->name_slug
                        ]);
                    }
                    $cities[$city->name_slug] = (object) [
                        $city->name,
                        $_message->counter,
                        $url
                    ];
                }
            }
        }


        return $cities;
    }
```

In my older version of the app I can access the values of the array in that way:

```
@foreach($provider->cityList() as $_city)
                                        <strong style="color:#E11F00;">{{ $_city->name }}{{ ($loop->last == false) ? ',' : '' }}</strong>
                                    @endforeach
```

This is the example @dd($provider->cityList())

```
array:1 [▼
  "vienna" => {#462 ▼
    +"0": "Vienna"
    +"1": 6
    +"2": null
  }
]
```

Is there an easy way to fix that? Because i can't find the way to change the array to:

```
array:1 [▼
  "vienna" => {#462 ▼
    +"name": "Vienna"
    +"count": 6
    +"url": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this part of code

```
 $cities[$city->name_slug] = (object) [
   $city->name,
   $_message->counter,
   $url
];
```

```php
 $cities[$city->name_slug] = (object) [
  'name' => $city->name,
  'count' => $_message->counter,
  'url' => $url
];
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't find that in the docs...